# Choosing correct way to write Images to folders for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to write Images to folders which are setup by me at run time. Now suppose there are 100 images, if I save it in two folders namely folder1 and folder2 both in Documents Directory. Both having equal no. of images i.e 50 in folder1 and remaining 50 in folder2. Next I want to fetch them wherever I need to.

So my question is, Is it right approach to choose two folders for half number of images or Just one folder for all the images. Which will be faster to read and write? Also what happens if number of images increase in single folder or more number of folders with some fixed number of images in it(like 5 folder each with 100 image or 1 with 500 images)?

I will be saving those paths in one field of my sqlite database. Also I will be querying for this path and showing the images and for now I want to do this for iOS device only. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Vish, if you already have the image file path stored in your sqlite file, it doesn't matter how many files you will store - I don't think that NSFileManager needs to go over all files. If you needed to go over the files, check the names, and only then open the images, that would be a different story and you would have performance issues. So do everything in one folder. I would suggest only two folders if you needed to save different kind of images, let's say, a cover image and a profile image for a user, and you would create one folder for covers and one folder for profile images.

You can use Grand Central Dispatch's `dispatch_async` for saving the images, so you won't block the main thread and UI. You could do it this way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    //save here the images
});
```

If you want to read more about NSFileManager and performance tips, [take a look here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH7-SW1).

Comment: Ok Nathan I know that we can use dispatch queue for background processes. I want to achieve best performance for my device to load the images. Yes offcourse I want to display those images as I asked in my question that I want to read+write. But even if I have my paths written in my DB then what exact mechanism is followed for reading the path? The file Manager's process doesn't skims all the images names, does they?

Comment: Updated the answer - I don't think that NSFileManager needs to go over all file names

Comment: Updated with resources

Comment: Ok those are general tips which must be taken care off while coding But I want to know the actual mechanism how the file manager reads path. Like does it sorts the names? or Does it loops through the names? So that I can apply it while coding for read+write. Thanks for your resource.

Comment: Agree with Natan. NSFileManager will just go to the path you give it from those you stored in the sqlite. It won't iterate through the files. I don't know it's internal mechanism for indexing even if it did but I imagine it would be pretty well optimised. Reading from disk is always s-l-o-w.

Comment: Playing devils advocate, you might consider if the images are not immense storing them as binary data in your persistent store. Core Data does a great job here and will with a little extra work provide you with fully formed objects including referenced binary data. Plus it's optimised for fast delivery and memory management. It has a reputation for being an advanced subject but I found the shorter guides from Apple to be great at getting me into it quickly.

Comment: But @MightyLeader, can't shift to core data at the moment so wanted to solve this problem of folder creation and image retrieval.!! Any relevant resources are welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's unlikely to be any performance benefits to writing to two folders instead of one. The NSFileManager code will handle all that for you anyway. Also you could make use of either dispatch_async or NSOperationQueue to keep the activity in the background and not block the UI which would give you better ways to manage performance.

If you're storing the paths in a persistent data store like sqlite then it makes sense to keep the paths to the files as simple as possible so again one folder would be best.

Comment: Ok @MightyLeader, agree if I keep the paths simple for my DB and store all the images in one. Now for single folder with 1000 images will skim through 1000 if the image is at the End i.e Worst case. and for 5 folders the DB path will be DocumentDirectory/5_folder/ in that only through 100 images. SO!!